# Exception handling in version agnostic code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, exception

I have a simple task at hand...handling exception so the code does not throw IncompleteRead when using urllib/urllib2 between python2.x/3.x

**for python2**

```
try:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(urls).read()
except httplib.IncompleteRead, e:
    page = e.partial
```

**for python3**

```
try:
    page = request.urlopen(urls).read()
except (http.client.IncompleteRead) as e:
    page = e.partial
```

now since the module itself are different, how to do a try-except when i have no idea which python version will my users be running?

I cannot check for python version within my try-except as well...or can I?

is there a way to catch its super class so it becomes same for both python version? if yes, how?

Comment: Might be a better way, but you can check which version of python is running your script using `sys.version`

Comment: okay...but once i get the version, how do i handle the exception? i just have a try-except block in my code...

Comment: Unless you need Python 2.5, you can use new-style `except:` statements in 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

```
try:
    from httplib import IncompleteRead
    import urllib2 as httpclient
except ImportError:
    from http.client import IncompleteRead
    import request as httpclient
```

Then use:

```
try:
    page = httpclient.urlopen(urls).read()
except IncompleteRead as e:
    page = e.partial
```

in both python2 and python3.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you need Python 2.5, you can use new-style except: statements in 2.x.

So, the only difference is the module names. You can `try` both manually, as in [Sraw's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50361518/908494). But you should probably be using `six`, `futurize`, or `modernize`, as [the official porting docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) and most other dual-versioning and porting guides recommend, and this is exactly the kind of thing that they're good for.

---

With [`six.moves`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/#module-six.moves):

```
from six.moves import http_client
from six.moves import urllib_request

try:
    page = urllib_request.urlopen(urls).read()
except http_client.IncompleteRead as e:
    page = e.partial
```

---

Or, with [`future`](http://python-future.org/automatic_conversion.html):

```
from future import standard_library
standard_library.install_aliases()
import http.client
import urllib.request, urllib.error, urllib.parse

try:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(urls).read()
except http.client.IncompleteRead as e:
    page = e.partial
```

Or, even better, just write the 2.7 code:

```
import httplib
import urllib2

try:
    page = urllib2.urlopen(urls).read()
except httplib.IncompleteRead as e:
    page = e.partial
```

… then run `futurize` on it, and it automatically gives you the `future` code above.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the porting docs, interesting distinction between version/feature detection.  Seems like my answer is bad practice, and has been deleted.

Comment: @chrisz Well, it's the right answer for some things, but I think in general Sraw's version is considered more pythonic. (Just like EAFP usually beats LBYL.)

Comment: I've only ever used it to tell people that my stuff *can't* be run with Python 2, which seems fine, but here I completely agree.

Comment: @chrisz For anything I'm not packaging for PyPI, I just `assert.version_info >= (3,6)` or whatever. That's good enough that if anyone complains "it doesn't work" and gives me any part of the error, I can tell them "Yeah, that's because Python 2.3 is not >= 3.6" instead of "That set comprehension looks perfectly valid, I don't know what to tell you without more information."

Answer (score 0):

You could do a try ... except on the import in an **init** module and then split your code into python2 and python3 modules:

```
try:
    import urllib2
    pyver2()
except ModuleNotFoundError:
    import requests
    pyver3()
```

Oh request doesn't do what you want, perhaps you mean 'requests' and requests doesn't have a 'urlopen' method you need to use 'get()'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP does mean the [`request`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) module in the `urllib` package that comes with the 3.x stdlib, which does have a `urlopen` function.

Comment: Also, this doesn't split the code into two modules, just into two functions in the same module. (Which means it won't help if you want to, e.g., use 3.x-only syntax in the 3.x module.) And maintaining two modules in parallel like this usually isn't worth it. It was the recommended solution back in 3.0-3.1 (especially if you could run `2to3` to generate the 3.x version if needed at install time), but if you look around PyPI, almost nobody's been doing it since around 3.3, and somewhere on Nick Coghlan's site there's a good blog post explaining why.